# Deleting a number digit by digit on a calculator screen

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

I want to delete a number digit by digit on the calculator screen but am only being able to delete the full number . Is there any method ?

```
-(IBAction)cancelInput:(float)result1{

        NSString *myString = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:result] stringValue];
        int str=[myString length]-1;
        NSString *newstring = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:str] stringValue];
        calculatorScreen.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:newstring];
        //NSLog(@"%d ",str);
}
```

Comment: try with this...if ( [string length] > 0)
    string = [string substringToIndex:[string length] - 1];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go,

```
NSString *myString = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:result] stringValue];
myString = [myString substringToIndex:[myString length]-1];
calculatorScreen.text= myString;
```

Comment: I want to delete a number digit wise like 456 becomes 45 . somehting like dat here it simply deletes the whole number

Comment: No. It only deletes the last character. Check your code again.

Comment: You could simplify this by removing the comparison to 0.

Comment: NONO!  The if statement was good, you just didn't need the >0 part!

Comment: @CodeFi I didnt get u ? where is the comparison ??

Answer (score 3):

int str=[myString length]-1 will only return the length of your string, say if your number is 9876, it will return 3(4-1) and your newstring will be 3.If you want to delete the last character you have to create substring of myString.

```
string = [string substringToIndex:[string length] - 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(IBAction)backPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
self.display.text=[self.display.text substringToIndex:[self.display.text length]-1];
if ( [self.display.text isEqualToString:@""] || [self.display.text isEqualToString:@"-"])
{
self.display.text =@"0";
}

}
```

This is the core function for the button. I took the liberty to add in the if feature so that it could handle some of the basic issues. As usual, replace display with your primary label. The If function help to counter check that your label does not become empty " " or have a negative sign "-" and will automatically replace it with "0", similar to clear in that aspect. in which you can run the clear method instead. But use

```
self.display.text =@"0";
```

for better clarification instead.

Comment: I would add if([self.display.text length] > 0) before shortening a string by 1 in order to prevent from crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for it:

```
else if([character isEqualToString:(NSString*) Delete])
{
    NSInteger index_of_char_to_remove=[_display length]-1;
    if(index_of_char_to_remove>=0)
    {
        [_display deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(index_of_char_to_remove, 1)];
        last_character_is_operator=NO;
    }
}
```

When press 'C' it will checked this condition and delete the data one by one

Comment: you must check this link http://www.datasprings.com/resources/articles-information/iphone-sdk-getting-started-example-code And download the code.